# How to only make changes to one workbook while opening?

Tags: excel, vba

On opening of a specific workbook I want to hide some excel functions, like scroll bars or ribbon. Problem is that all other woorkbooks are affected...I use "Workbook" & Open with the following:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open ()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""ribbon"", false)"
    Application.DisplayScrollBars=False
End Sub
```

I also tried the same using `With Application` and `With ThisWorkbook`.

I don't know how to limit the macro to work when only a specific Excel workbook is opening, without affecting other already opened woorkbooks, or workbooks which will be opened after the specific one is already open.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler - you can use Application-level events to respond to which workbook is currently active.

Answer (score 0):

The Ribbon lives at `Application` level; consider hiding it in `Workbook_SheetActivate` and showing it again in `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` handlers in `ThisWorkbook`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'invoked when ThisWorkbook is opened.
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
'invoked when any sheet in ThisWorkbook is activated.
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
'invoked when any sheet in ThisWorkbook is deactivated.
End Sub
```

Now, these events would be firing when activating/deactivating sheets in `ThisWorkbook`, ...and I would expect this to cause some kind of annoying flickering with the Ribbon whenever a sheet in `ThisWorkbook` deactivates and then another sheet in `ThisWorkbook` is activated immediately after.

You can use the `Sh` argument to determine whether the `ActiveSheet` is still in `ThisWorkbook`, and prevent hiding the Ribbon in `SheetDeactivate` then:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
'invoked when any sheet in ThisWorkbook is deactivated.
    If Not ActiveSheet.Parent Is ThisWorkbook Then
        CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon" 'will show the Ribbon if it's hidden
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
'invoked when any sheet in ThisWorkbook is activated.
    CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon" 'will show the Ribbon if it's hidden
    Application.DisplayScrollBars=False
End Sub
```

Consider toggling `Application.DisplayFullScreen` instead of invoking Excel4 macros or obscure MsoID commands.

Comment: There are two issues with `SheetActivate`: the first line raises the error `91` which is easily fixed with `Application.CommandBars...`. Why doesn't it error out in `SheetDeactive`, too? If I hide the scroll bars, how am I going to select (activate) another sheet (in `ThisWorkbook`)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Ctrl+PgUp/PgDown should still navigate between sheets (right?). That said if `DisplayFullScreen` does what the OP wants, I'd go with that.